# same mysql query takes much longer to execute on bare mariadb on specific linux box

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I am tracing down slow MySQL performance on the production server and encountered a strange issue - the same MySQL query takes much longer to execute on the production `CentOS 7.4.1708 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64` with 125GB of memory, when the same query, being run on the local instance on the same dump of the database executes much faster, specifically, it takes around 10-20s to finish on the local environment (osX box 16 GB of ram) and the 3-5mins or so on the production machine. Both machines used default MariaDB configs, and the query was the only one being run at the moment of testing.

**Mysql data directory is mounted on /home/mysql_data** may that be a reason?

The same MySQL dump was used, the query was run from console `MySQL dbname < test.sql` so the bottleneck is apparently is the database, the mariadb was installed from ports on macos and from repo on linux (I've tried custom compiled version as well) with no difference.

I started to be suspicious about the hardware, any hint or suggestion would be much appreciated, attaching `pt-summary` output

```
# Percona Toolkit System Summary Report ######################
        Date | 2019-12-09 09:35:10 UTC (local TZ: EST -0500)
    Hostname | ...
      Uptime | 727 days, 23:51,  3 users,  load average: 1.29, 1.48, 1.75
      System | Supermicro; X10DRH; v123456789 (Rack Mount Chassis)
 Service Tag | 123456789
    Platform | Linux
     Release | CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
      Kernel | 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
Architecture | CPU = 64-bit, OS = 64-bit
   Threading | NPTL 2.17
    Compiler | GNU CC version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16).
     SELinux | Disabled
 Virtualized | VMWare
# Processor ##################################################
  Processors | physical = 2, cores = 16, virtual = 32, hyperthreading = yes
      Speeds | 1x2596.593, 1x2597.156, 1x2600.437, 1x2601.093, 1x2605.312, 1x2607.093, 1x2610.375, 1x2613.937, 1x2619.562, 1x2655.750, 1x2752.312, 1x2759.343, 1x2769.937, 1x2780.906, 1x2835.000, 1x2841.281, 1x2851.593, 1x2855.437, 1x2880.000, 1x2882.812, 1x2896.968, 1x2913.187, 1x2923.500, 1x2945.625, 1x2951.062, 1x2974.312, 1x3004.500, 1x3029.343, 1x3062.625, 1x3076.218, 1x3166.593, 1x3191.250
      Models | 32xIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
      Caches | 32x20480 KB
# Memory #####################################################
       Total | 125.9G
        Free | 2.3G
        Used | physical = 14.5G, swap allocated = 0.0, swap used = 0.0, virtual = 14.5G
      Shared | 4.1G
     Buffers | 109.1G
      Caches | 106.7G
       Dirty | 636 kB
     UsedRSS | 15.4G
  Swappiness | 1
 DirtyPolicy | 30, 10
 DirtyStatus | 0, 0
  Locator   Size     Speed             Form Factor   Type          Type Detail
  ========= ======== ================= ============= ============= ===========
  P1_DIMMA1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMB1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMC1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMD1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMME1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMF1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMG1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMH1 16384 MB 2133 MHz          DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMA2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMB2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMC2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P1_DIMMD2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMME2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMF2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMG2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
  P2_DIMMH2 {EMPTY}  Unknown           DIMM          DDR4          Synchronous
# Mounted Filesystems ########################################
  Filesystem  Size Used Type     Opts                                                   Mountpoint
  /dev/md2    421G  62% ext4     rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered       /R
  /dev/md2    421G  62% ext4     rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered       /R
  devtmpfs     63G   0% devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=65953940k,nr_inodes=16488485,mode=755 /dev
  tmpfs        13G   0% tmpfs    rw                                                     /run/user/0
  tmpfs        13G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755                               /run/user/0
  tmpfs        13G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13197492k,mode=700       /run/user/0
  tmpfs        13G   0% tmpfs    ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755                        /run/user/0
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw                                                     /dev/shm
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755                               /dev/shm
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13197492k,mode=700       /dev/shm
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755                        /dev/shm
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw                                                     /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755                               /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13197492k,mode=700       /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs        63G   0% tmpfs    ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755                        /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs        63G   7% tmpfs    rw                                                     /run
  tmpfs        63G   7% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755                               /run
  tmpfs        63G   7% tmpfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=13197492k,mode=700       /run
  tmpfs        63G   7% tmpfs    ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755                        /run
# Disk Schedulers And Queue Size #############################
        dm-0 | 128
         md0 | 128
         md1 | 128
         md2 | 128
        nbd0 | [deadline] 128
        nbd1 | [deadline] 128
       nbd10 | [deadline] 128
       nbd11 | [deadline] 128
       nbd12 | [deadline] 128
       nbd13 | [deadline] 128
       nbd14 | [deadline] 128
       nbd15 | [deadline] 128
        nbd2 | [deadline] 128
        nbd3 | [deadline] 128
        nbd4 | [deadline] 128
        nbd5 | [deadline] 128
        nbd6 | [deadline] 128
        nbd7 | [deadline] 128
        nbd8 | [deadline] 128
        nbd9 | [deadline] 128
         sda | [deadline] 128
         sdb | [deadline] 128
# Disk Partioning ############################################
Device       Type      Start        End               Size
============ ==== ========== ========== ==================
/dev/dm-0    Disk                             107374182400
/dev/md1     Disk                              20970405888
/dev/md2     Disk                             458591502336
/dev/sda     Disk                             480103981056
/dev/sda1    Part       4096   40962047        20970470912
/dev/sda2    Part   40962048  936648703       458591567360
/dev/sda3    Part  936648704  937695231          535821824
/dev/sdb     Disk                             480103981056
/dev/sdb1    Part       4096   40962047        20970470912
/dev/sdb2    Part   40962048  936648703       458591567360
/dev/sdb3    Part  936648704  937695231          535821824
# Kernel Inode State #########################################
dentry-state | 19102026 19047745    45  0   0   0
     file-nr | 3328 0   512000
    inode-nr | 1262883  278591
# LVM Volumes ################################################
Unable to collect information
# LVM Volume Groups ##########################################
Unable to collect information
# RAID Controller ############################################
  Controller | Fusion-MPT SAS
# Network Config #############################################
  Controller | Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
  Controller | Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
 FIN Timeout | 60
  Port Range | 61000
# Interface Statistics #######################################
  interface  rx_bytes rx_packets  rx_errors   tx_bytes tx_packets  tx_errors
  ========= ========= ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========
  lo       12500000000000 8000000000          0 12500000000000 8000000000          0
  bond0             0          0          0          0          0          0
  dummy0            0          0          0          0          0          0
  ifb0              0          0          0          0          0          0
  ifb1              0          0          0          0          0          0
  eth0     1000000000000 7000000000          0 5000000000000 4500000000          0
  eth1              0          0          0          0          0          0
  teql0             0          0          0          0          0          0
  tunl0@NONE          0          0          0          0          0          0
  sit0@NONE          0          0          0          0          0          0
  ip6tnl0@NONE          0          0          0          0          0          0
  docker0   175000000     450000          0  250000000     450000          0
# Network Devices ############################################
  Device    Speed     Duplex
  ========= ========= =========
  bond0      Unknown!   Unknown!  
  eth0       1000Mb/s   Full      
  eth1       Unknown!   Unknown!  
  docker0                         
# Network Connections ########################################
  Connections from remote IP addresses
    35.158.140.87       2
    45.94.25.205        1
    46.38.144.17        4
    46.38.144.32        2
    46.38.144.57        3
    46.38.144.146       2
    46.38.144.179       3
    46.38.144.202       1
    46.229.168.150      1
    54.36.148.89        1
    54.36.148.155       1
    54.36.148.199       1
    54.36.149.27        1
    54.36.150.48        1
    54.36.150.58        1
    54.36.150.85        1
    54.36.150.138       1
    63.135.176.20       2
    64.250.124.70       2
    66.249.64.104       1
    66.249.64.106       1
    66.249.64.234       1
    66.249.64.236       1
    74.121.199.234      2
    92.118.38.38        4
    121.66.252.155      1
    127.0.0.1          80
    136.145.228.221     2
    160.10.5.26         2
    162.247.242.5       3
    178.62.77.163       6
    188.163.83.193      3
    203.125.15.242      1
  Connections to local IP addresses
    54.39.202.16       35
    127.0.0.1          80
    158.69.185.152      1
    167.114.208.91     25
  Connections to top 10 local ports
    22                  4
    25                  4
    443                20
    51554               1
    52622               1
    587                15
    59914               1
    80                  2
    8891                2
    9000               60
  States of connections
    CLOSE_WAIT          1
    ESTABLISHED        25
    LISTEN             35
    TIME_WAIT         125
# Top Processes ##############################################
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
12492 mysql     20   0 61.652g 0.011t  15876 S  93.8  8.6 312:39.96 mysqld
30259 root      20   0 1023576  28600   4676 S  12.5  0.0  38262:50 newrelic-i+
    1 root      20   0  191620   3876   1664 S   0.0  0.0   1429:05 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:32.51 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0 107:31.39 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1407:32 rcu_sched
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:37.04 migration/0
# Notable Processes ##########################################
  PID    OOM    COMMAND
29337    -17    sshd
26454    -17    systemd-udevd
27610    -17    postgres
# Simplified and fuzzy rounded vmstat (wait please) ##########
  procs  ---swap-- -----io---- ---system---- --------cpu--------
   r  b    si   so    bi    bo     ir     cs  us  sy  il  wa  st
   2  0     0    0     2    80      0      0   5   0  95   0   0
   2  0     0    0     0   900   2500   4000   5   1  94   0   0
   3  0     0    0     0  1000   2250   4500  10   0  89   0   0
   1  0     0    0     0   600   1500   2000   6   0  94   0   0
   7  0     0    0     0   250   2000   2000   9   1  90   0   0
# Memory mamagement ##########################################
Unable to get Transparent huge pages status.
# The End ####################################################
```

sysctl memory settings:

```
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 8192
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 30
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.drop_caches = 0
vm.heap_stack_gap = 65536
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256 256 32
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.memory_failure_early_kill = 0
vm.memory_failure_recovery = 1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 45951
vm.min_slab_ratio = 5
vm.min_unmapped_ratio = 1
vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
vm.numa_zonelist_order = default
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.scan_unevictable_pages = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
vm.swappiness = 1
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
```

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` on each machine?  Do you have only 14.5GB on each machine?  Let's see the query; it may give some clues.

Comment: Please post the pt-summary and sysctl memory settings from your local machine for reference and comparison.   Usually, Hyperthreading is recommended to be OFF when using MySQL.

Comment: Additional information requests from your production server.
Any SSD or NVME for data storage? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.